# IBM Worklight 8.0 Adapter to invoke Java code

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, worklight-runtime

We are using MobileFirst 8.0 adapters for mobile application development.
Earlier we were using Mobile first 7.1 where we use to invoke java files as below.

```
var salt =com.Base64EncoderDecoder.decode(salt);
```

The above file Base64EncoderDecoder.class was part of worklight .war file.
Can same approach be achieved using Mobile first 8.0 ? Please suggest how this can be achieved in 8.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can still achieve the same functionality with IBM MFP 8.0.
The difference is that , with MFP 8.0, the Java class will be packaged within your adapter project itself.

For more details and a working sample, refer to [this link](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/javascript-adapters/using-java-in-javascript-adapters/).